# Variance of Random Exponential Variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables, variance

Just a note: this is a homework question, so feel free to prod me towards the answer if you want :) Also, I'm pretty bad at statistics so sorry in advance if I'm stupid :/

For some $ X_1 ... X_n \sim Exp(\lambda) $ i.i.d. random variables, I have an estimator:

> $ \hat{\lambda} = (\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}{X_i})^{-1} $

I need to use the CLT to determine an approximate $ 1 - \alpha $ stochastic confidence interval for $ \frac{1}{\lambda} $ based on $ \hat{\lambda} $.

Obviously, I need to find the mean $ \mu $ and variance $ \sigma^2 $ so that I can normalise it (i.e. $ \frac{\hat{\lambda} - \mu}{\sigma} \sim Normal(0, 1) $).

The thing I'm not sure on is how to find $ \mu $ and $ \sigma^2 $.

I'm mostly comfortable saying that since $ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}{X_i} $ is the sample mean, $ E[\hat{\lambda}] = \lambda $

With the variance though, I'm really not sure. My best guess is that it's:

$$
Var(\hat{\lambda}) = (Var(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}{X_i}))^{-1}
$$

$$
Var(\hat{\lambda}) = (\frac{1}{n^2} \dot{} Var(\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{X_i}))^{-1} 
$$

$$
Var(\hat{\lambda}) = (\frac{1}{n^2} \dot{} n \dot{} \frac{1}{\lambda^2} )^{-1}
$$

$$
Var(\hat{\lambda}) = n\lambda^2
$$

But I'm not sure if you're do that with variances. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The mean and standard deviation of an exponential distribution are the same. See Wikipedia on 'exponential distribution'.

Comment: The identity $\mathrm{var}(1/Y)=1/\mathrm{var}(Y)$ is of course ludicrous. Rather, note that the most standard CLT yields $$\frac1{\hat\lambda_n}=\frac1\lambda+\frac1{\lambda\sqrt{n}}Z_n$$ where $Z_n$ is asymptotically standard normal, hence, if $P(a<Z<b)=1-\alpha$, with $Z$ standard normal, then $$P\left(a<\sqrt{n}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\hat\lambda_n}-1\right)<b\right)\approx1-\alpha$$ Can you finish this?

Comment: How did you get that $ \frac{1}{\hat{\lambda}} = \frac{1}{\lambda} + \frac{1}{\lambda \sqrt{n}} $? Also, could I just flip $ \hat{\lambda} $? Cause I'm looking for a confidence interval for $ 1/\lambda $ anyway?

Comment: Because $ E[\frac{1}{\hat{\lambda}}] = 1/\lambda$ and $ Var(\frac{1}{\hat{\lambda}}) = n\lambda^2$, right?