# Convergence in probability for $\exp(\lambda)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be i.i.d r.v.s whose distribution is $\exp(\lambda)$. The c.d.f. function $F_{\lambda}(x) = 1-e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x>0$ and $0$ otherwise, as known. Also

$$\hat{\lambda}=\frac1{\overline{X}} \overset{p}\longrightarrow \lambda = \frac1{\mathbb{E}_{\lambda}(X)}$$ and the asymptotic distribution of $\sqrt{n}(1/\bar{X}-\lambda)$ is $N(0,A)$.

My two questions are:

1. How can I show that $\hat{\lambda}$ converges in probability to $\lambda$ for this exponential distribution case? I would like to apply the definition of convergence in probability s.t. $\Pr(|X_n-X_0|<\epsilon)=1$, but got confused when I face such reciprocal values and sample mean.
2. Can anyone tell me how to compute $A$, the variance of the limiting distribution, and the method of proposing a consistent estimate $\hat{A}$ for $A$?

Comment: In #1 it seems to me that you are asked to prove a special case of a general result, that convergence in probability is preserved under continuous transformations. The proof of this result can be just looked up now that you know what to look for. I don't think I really understand #2 because if $X$ is an exponential r.v. then $1/X$ is not even integrable. I especially don't understand what you mean by "a consistent estimate for the variance" since this variance is just given by some combination of integrals (which, as I mentioned before, add up to $+\infty$).

Comment: @Ian Sorry, for question 2 it was not you but me who did not really understand it. Can you let me know for this case how the variance of distribution comes out? What I meant by "proposing a consistent estimate" was I would like to get an estimate of variance which converges in probability.

Comment: Hmmm... $1/X_i$ is not integrable so what could $\mathrm{var}(1/X_i)$ possibly mean?

Comment: @Did I made some edits for that part. Now the question should be I just have to calculate the variance from the beginning.

Comment: For 1) is it just applying WLLN?

Comment: @Ian Oh, I feel like I got what you meant by 1). You meant because $\bar{X}$ converges to $\mu$ in probability, their reciprocals behave the same when I define the function $g(X) = 1/X$?

Comment: 1) is not just WLLN, because you're taking a transformation of the sample mean and hoping that you can exchange some operations. You can do this if that transformation is continuous, as I said, but this requires proof (and this proof is not so trivial if the transformation is not *uniformly* continuous, which yours is not). 2) does not even make sense on its face: $1/\overline{X}$ will not be integrable so it will not satisfy CLT. There is no way to "slightly tweak" the statement in 2) to arrive at something that satisfies CLT.

Comment: @Ian I see......An idea of using delta method has just come out from my head when I calculate A.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Was the problem given to you this way? Or are you just trying to understand how to estimate the rate of a Poisson process given $n$ jump times?

Comment: Again there is no hope of even calculating $A$, the variance of $\sqrt{n}(1/\overline{X}-\lambda)$ is $+\infty$.

Comment: @Ian Yes, it was a given problem, but for the CLT I misunderstood it and removed the phrase.

Comment: $A=\lambda$. (Use [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992614/variance-of-random-exponential-variables#comment4091306_1992614).)

Comment: @Did I'm a bit perplexed by that comment myself; where are you getting finite moments for (in the notation of that question) $\frac{1}{\hat{\lambda}_n}$? It seems to me that those should all have mean $+\infty$.

Comment: @Ian Fortunately, the existence of moments is not required for convergence in distribution to a normal distribution, to hold. What is unclear in the comment on the other page?

Comment: Now that I check again, I think these two questions are not in the same setting. In the other question, you have $\hat{\lambda}_n$ which is the reciprocal of the sample mean of the *times*, and then you take the reciprocal of *that* as an estimate of the mean time. This is a roundabout way of implementing the standard estimator for the mean. But in this question, my impression is that the OP is trying to use the reciprocal of the mean time as an estimate of the *rate*. But this will not go through the same way because the reciprocal of the mean time has a "bad" distribution.

Comment: (Cont.)  It will still converge in probability to $\lambda$ but the finite-$n$ distributions will have a fat tail, which makes me suspect that you will not be able to rescale to get a normal distribution limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest two approaches to calculate the asymptotic variance:

1) Under some regularity conditions (satisfied for the exponential distribution), maximum-likelihood-estimators $\hat{\theta}_{ML}$ for a parameter $\theta$ from iid samples are asymptotically normal (more exactly, $\sqrt{n} (\hat{\theta}_{ML} - \theta)\rightarrow N(0,A)$ in distribution).

The asymptotic variance A is then given by the inverse of the Fisher information $E\left(\left(\frac{d}{d\theta}\ln f(X|\theta)\right)^2\right)$.

The ML estimator for the parameter $\lambda$ of an exponential distribution is the inverse of the sample mean (easy exercise). Also,
$$\frac{d}{d\lambda}\ln f(x|\lambda) = \frac{d}{d\lambda}\ln (\lambda\exp(-\lambda x)) = \frac{d}{d\lambda}(\ln \lambda - \lambda x)=\frac{1}{\lambda}-x $$
and so
$$E\left(\left(\frac{d}{d\theta}\ln f(X|\theta)\right)^2\right) = E\left(\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}-X\right)^2\right)=Var\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}-X\right)=Var(X)=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}.$$
Therefore, the asymptotic variance A is $\lambda^2$.

2) If you're not familiar with ML-estimators and Fisher information, use Taylor-linearization (also known as the Delta method in this context):

Define $f(x)=\sqrt{n}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{x} -\lambda\right)$. Then, $f'(x)=-\sqrt{n}\cdot\frac{1}{x^2}$ (for $x>0$). Taylor-linearization says
$$f(x)\approx f(x_0) + (x-x_0)\cdot f'(x_0),$$
if $x$ is in the vicinity of $x_0$.
Now plug in $\bar{X}$ for $x$ and $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ for $x_0$:
$$f(\bar{X})\approx f(\frac{1}{\lambda}) + (\bar{X}-\frac{1}{\lambda})\cdot f'(\frac{1}\lambda),$$
whenever $\bar{X}$ is in the vicinity of $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. Note that $\bar{X}\rightarrow \frac{1}{\lambda}$ by the WLLN, so the approximation gets better the larger $n$ gets (heuristically speaking).

Now look at the variance of $f(\bar{X})$:
$$ Var\left( f(\bar{X}) \right) =
  Var\left( \sqrt{n}\cdot\left( \frac{1}{\bar{X}} -\lambda\right) \right) \approx Var\left( f(\frac{1}{\lambda}) + (\bar{X}-\frac{1}{\lambda})\cdot f'(\frac{1}\lambda) \right)$$
$$=Var(\bar{X})\cdot f'(\frac{1}\lambda)^2 = \frac{1}{n\lambda^2}\cdot(-\sqrt{n}\lambda^2)^2 = \lambda^2.$$

Ok, so the asymptotic variance is $\lambda^2$. But you don't know $\lambda$, so you have to estimate the variance. Plug in the estimator for $\lambda$ (i.e. $\frac{1}{\bar{X}}$) to get an estimator for the asymptotic variance:
$$\hat{A} =\frac{1}{\bar{X}^2}.$$
Consistency follows, since convergence in probability is preserved under continuous transformations.

Comment: I guess I'm a little bit confused as to what is actually happening here. If I have an iid sample from the exponential distribution with rate $\lambda$, the distribution of $\frac{1}{\overline{X}}$ should be fairly bad. In particular $P(1/\overline{X}>z)$ is on the order of $1/z$ as $z \to \infty$ (although $z P(1/\overline{X}>z)$ will decay with $n$). Can you explain how an asymptotic variance nevertheless makes sense?

Comment: @Ian : I see your point, but I can't provide a good intuition on this. In a series $X_i$ of rv's, every $X_i$ might be non-integrable, but the limiting distribution might still be integrable. My own intuition on this just relies on the Taylor expansion.

Comment: The limiting distribution might be integrable but that does not mean that any of the approximate are, so the sense of it being an *asymptotic* variance is shaky. I also don't buy the Taylor argument on its face because it is ignoring the behavior on the bad set, which could be quite bad indeed if the tail is sufficiently fat.

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to say is that these estimators for $\lambda$ and for the variance i.e. $\lambda^2$ are not just biased but *extremely* biased, having a mean infinitely larger than the desired mean.